# Does MS Visual Studio 2012 Express include C#, Visual Basic, C++ at the same time?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I would like to download a newer version of VS Express, but It seems to me that VS 2012 includes Basic, C# and C++ as well, however I only need C++... 
Nevertheless I can download VS 2010 which includes only C++. (Visual C++ Express)

So I don't want to waste hard disk with unnecessery packages. Does 2012 include all these languages? What would you do in my place?

Comment: Yes, it has all three that you mentioned. I don't know of a way not to include them, but it was quite a while ago when I got it, so there might have been something obvious that I forgot.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2012-express

Comment: I don't know what is the case with VS 2012, but with 2010 you can choose which languages to install.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's listed at 3GB in my programs. It's not that much space.

Comment: @DCoder Are you quite sure about that?

Comment: I *was*, but it seems the current installer they provide doesn't offer the language selection anymore... sorry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

VS2012 is the first version of Visual Studio where the Express editions are no longer broken out by language preference.  Guessing at a reason for this, it might have something to do with the proliferation of target platforms between these Express editions.  New in VS2012 is the distinction between the Desktop, Windows 8 and Phone editions.  If they would have kept the language choices, that would have added 8 more editions to choose from.

Be sure to pick the right one.  With high odds that you want the Desktop edition unless you specifically want to target the Windows 8 Store or Phone.  VB.NET, C# will come along with the ride, JS if you pick Store or Phone.

You could delete the VB and C# subdirectories after installing it but that will recover very little disk space.  These languages share a lot of the plumbing in VS.  Especially since C++ got integrated into the build system.  Their compilers are not actually part of VS, they are part of .NET

Comment: +1 because it's utterly silly to have my answer at 1 and this one at 0.

Answer (score 1):

Each Express edition is for a single language/purpose.

The full Visual Studio, however, combines everything into one big package.

---

**EDIT**: Chris, who's using it, notes in a comment that the [Dekstop edition](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop#product-express-desktop-details) of Visual Studio Express indeed supports multiple languages.

Comment: This is true is 2010, but I don't think so in 2012. That's probably why. AFAIK, the express 2012 edition just has fewer features.

Comment: Well, for starters, my Visual Express 2012 for Desktops has Visual Basic, C#, and C++ packaged into it. The Express 2010 ones are all one language each.

Comment: ok thanks. so you didn't "I don't think so", as you wrote. i'm just using the full visual studio 2012. i helped argue for the introduction of the desktop edition (http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop#product-express-desktop-details) -- it was added late  --  but i didn't notice the multi-language thing.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf If its so could you pls link a download site for Visual Studio 2012 Express **only** with C++?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, You helped argue? I'm very grateful for that, thanks! Anyway, I'm sorry, I should say what I mean. I agree that isn't particularly nice to go from.

Comment: @Chris So Is there any way to download VS Express 2012 only with C++?

Comment: @gen, Not that I know of. To be fair, with it being late, I'm glad there was one at all.

Comment: @gen - If you can't find it here http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads - (i can't) then no.